# Setting Max Length of Links in D3 Tree Layout

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a tree graph very similar to the one here: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/999346 and I would like to limit the spacing vertically of the nodes; if you look at the tree you will see that when there are just two nodes, they take up the entire canvas (the link between the two nodes is very long), and as other nodes are inserted, the link(s) are resized to fit.  I would like to limit the link length to some max number so that the tree is more compact with fewer nodes.

Comment: Use `tree.separation()`. See [the documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Tree-Layout#separation).

Answer (score 2):

[Jason Davies](https://stackoverflow.com/users/64009/jason-davies)' approach of looping over the nodes after d3.layout.tree has run and overwriting each node's y-value works well for me. (described in this [d3 github issue comment](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/issues/213))

So, something like

```
nodes.forEach(function(node){
    node.y = (node.depth * 90); // 90px per level.
})
```